# Why might I get poor NAT throughput on a Cisco router?

Tags: networking, cisco

Here's my show ver IOS version:

Cisco IOS Software, C2600 Software (C2600-ENTBASE-M), Version 12.3(11)T2, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)

It's a Cisco 2621 router providing NAT between fa0/0 and fa0/1. The WAN connection is tested from a device alongside this router as being approx 40mbit. A speedtest of a device accessing the WAN via this NAT router shows almost exactly 20mbit.

Can anyone suggest what might be limiting throughput here?

Comment: How big is the NAT network behind the router, a /24?

Comment: You need to troubleshoot. Is the CPU maxed (`show proc cpu`)? Are the packets being fast switched (`show int fa0/0 switching`)? How many packets per second are moving in each direction?

Comment: The NAT is being performed by the CPU, not by the hardware ASICs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is your routers performance  that limiting you. Here is a [cisco's routers performance PDF](http://www.cisco.com/web/partners/downloads/765/tools/quickreference/routerperformance.pdf)

Your router throughput is roughly 12.80 Mbps.

Comment: Also remember that performance sheet is for plain packet forwarding without any kind of NAT or other service(QoS/NBAR/...).